# How to Create Array in javascript by loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is code  I fix number  1 2 3 .... to 10

I want to create data array by loop

```
 data = [  {  value: ProductPiecePerBundle* 1 ,   label: "1   "+ ProductPiecePerBundle*1  },

           {  value: ProductPiecePerBundle* 2 ,   label:  "2    "+ ProductPiecePerBundle*2  } ,

           {  value: ProductPiecePerBundle* 3 ,   label:  "3    "+ ProductPiecePerBundle*3  } ,

            .....

          {  value: ProductPiecePerBundle*10 ,   label:  "10    "+ ProductPiecePerBundle*10 } ,

      ];
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: sorry This is first question  but I get Answer  Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information is needed to answer your question. But in general, to create an array using a for loop would look something like this:

```
var ProductPiecePerBundle = 2;
var data = [];

for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    myArray.push({value: ProductPiecePerBundle * i , label: i + " "+ ProductPiecePerBundle * i });
}
```

To append something to an array you use the [push method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp).

Comment: This is my first time to ask Question  Thank you ><

Answer (score 1):

```
    var data = [];
    var x = 1
    for(var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
        data[i] = {value: ProductPiecePerBundle*x , label: "" + x + " "+ ProductPiecePerBundle*x}
        x++
    }
```